# pass data to broadcast receiver that already has intent filter coming from activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

when the phone is connected to the bluetooth in the car. I want my app to switch on automatically. to do this i have to save the paired car bluetooth device name to a string. then when the phones bluetooth is connected to something. I have to check if its the car. If it is i want to start a service.

I'm having difficulty passing the string that contains the bluetooth car device name to the receiver, as my receiver is already receiving a intent filter to listen out for ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED. is it possible to send a intent & an intent filter to the same receiver.

How can I can send the btdeviceName string from the activity to the receiver in this case.

**Main Activity**

```
 private void addDrawerItems() {

    final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothBroadcast = new BluetoothReceiver();
    final IntentFilter blueToothFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);


    final Intent btbroadcastIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothReceiver.class);
    btbroadcastIntent.putExtra("btDeviceName", mPairedBluetoothDevice);


    String[] osArray = {"Bluetooth Auto Start", "Reply to Calls", "Reply to sms", "Customise Message"};

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, osArray);


    if (mIsPremiumUser) {
        mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    } else {
        mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    }

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    mDrawerList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            if (position == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "blue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                showBluetoothDialog();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view;

            if (!mIsPremiumUser) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Upgrade", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }


            switch (position) {

                case 0:

                    if (ctv.isChecked()) {

                        if (!isblueToothRegistered) {
                            registerReceiver(bluetoothBroadcast, blueToothFilter);
                            sendBroadcast(btbroadcastIntent);
                            isblueToothRegistered = true;
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (isblueToothRegistered) {
                            unregisterReceiver(bluetoothBroadcast);
                            isblueToothRegistered = false;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
```

**BluetoothReceiver**

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private MainActivity ma;
private String pairedDevice;


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Toast.makeText(context, "Receieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    pairedDevice = intent.getStringExtra("btDeviceName");
    Toast.makeText(context, pairedDevice + "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    final BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);


    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        if (device.getName().equals(pairedDevice)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, device.getName() + " 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IntentFilter` can have multiple actions. So start by creating your own custom action name to listen for and add it to the `blueToothFilter`.

```
blueToothFilter.addAction("my.custom.action");
```

Once you register the `bluetoothBroadcast` receiver with this `IntentFilter` it will now receive calls for both actions. Add another condition in `onReceive` to handle your new custom action.

Finally in your `Activity` send a broadcast with your custom action and the device name when ready.

```
Intent intent = new Intent()
        .setAction("my.custom.action")
        .putExtra("btDeviceName", mPairedBluetoothDevice);

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

---

UPDATE

I now understand that you want both the `BluetoothDevice device` and `String pairedDevice` in a single call to `onReceive()`. That is not possible since those variables are taken from separate actions and each action calls `onReceive()` once.

To fix this you can change the `BluetoothReceiver` to be an inner class of your `Activity`so you can keep a reference to the data you need there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still a bit confused about how this looks l in the broadcast receiver though ?

Comment: how do i differentiate the two actions in the receiver ?

Comment: You check what is returned from `intent.getAction()`. Right now you have two cases, one for `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` and another for `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED`. You need to add a third that checks for your custom action name whatever you choose to call it (in my example its `my.custom.action`). If that is the action then you know the intent will have the `btDeviceName` extra in it.

Comment: I think I see part of the confusion now. You are currently expecting to be able to receive the device from the `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` action and the name of the device from your custom `Action` in the same `onReceive` event. Unfortunately that is not going to happen since these are separate events. You will receive two separate calls to `onReceive`, one containing the `String pairedDevice` and the other containg the `BluetoothDevice device`. One way to make this work is to make the `BluetoothReceiver` an inner class to the `Activity` so you can keep a reference to the data you need there.

Comment: yup that did the job ! having the receiver as an inner class in the main activity worked. do you want to update your answer, to say that? its a bit silly  that the simplest thing of just passing a string variable from one class to another proved so difficult!

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer with the relevant bits from the comment.

Comment: Thanks yourself have a nice evening 